# Change the color of clicked element with color picker

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change the color of clicked element. I tried this but was not working. When users clicked on any element e.g footer then, after clicking on that element "htm5 colour picker" should appear and then users can pick the color from it and that chosen color should be applied imminently in real-time. I don't want to save on my database or use ajax + php, See my code at below

May be we can add inline CSS using setAttribute("style", " ").

```js
$('body').click(function(event) {
  alert($(event.target).attr('class'));
  var colorWell;
  var defaultColor = "#0000ff";

  window.addEventListener("load", startup, false);

  function startup() {
    colorWell = document.querySelector("#colorWell");
    colorWell.value = defaultColor;
    colorWell.addEventListener("input", updateFirst, false);
    colorWell.addEventListener("change", updateAll, false);
    colorWell.select();
  }


  function updateFirst(event) {

    var p = event.target.id;

    if (p) {
      p.style.color = event.target.value;
    }
  }

  function updateAll(event) {
    document.querySelectorAll("p").forEach(function(p) {
      p.style.color = event.target.value;
    });
  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label for="colorWell">Color:</label>
<input type="color" value="#ff0000" id="colorWell">
```

Comment: Your jsFiddle link is broken

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/color see the last example in this link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the whole snippet on body click, that means the line where you are attaching `window.onload` gets called on window onload which has already happened. You can just call the method startup on body click. If you want to call startup on body load you have to remove the body o'clock method or move the window.onload before body click.

```js
$(document).click(function(event) {
  change(event.target, {left: event.pageX, top: event.pageY});
});

$(()=>{ $('#colorWell').on('click', (e) => e.stopPropagation()); });

var defaultColor = "#0000ff";
function change(target, pos) {
  var picker = $('#colorWell');
  picker.css(pos).off('change');
  setTimeout(() => picker.click(), 50);
  picker.on('change', function(e){
    $(target).css({color: $(this).val() || defaultColor});
    picker.css({top: '-50px'});
  });
}
```

```css
#colorWell {
  position: absolute;
  top: -50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="color" value="#ff0000" id="colorWell">

<p> click Me P tag</p>

<div> click me div tag </div>
```

Comment: thank you, input type tag should be hidden & this color picker should be work on any element, just by clicking on it, where we don't the id of any element. so when user click on unknown element that element's id should become target id . I think we should use $('body').on('click', function(e){
    alert(e.target.id);    
});  & <input type="color" value="#ff0000" id="colorWell" style="opacity: 0; visibility: hidden; position: absolute;"> this code also be generated dynamically through JavaScript on e.target.id. after new color is applied this "input type" tag html line also be removed

Comment: @gigabyteservice is this what you need? updated answer

Comment: better but this code is only work for font color is I want to change the bg color then it's not working & also <input type ="color" should be generate dynamically then this input type will change the color I have tried and input type is generated but the color changing not working. may be I'm not using on() jquery function.

Comment: her the code that can generate input type dynamically    $(document).click(function(event){
  if (event.target.id){
    var pratik = event.target.id; 
var newElem = document.createElement('input');
    newElem.type = "color";      
    newElem.id = "colorWell";  
   
    document.getElementById(pratik).appendChild(newElem);
  }                         after changing the color I also want to remove the element so remove() is sufficient

Comment: I am unable to comprehend what exactly you need

Comment: <input type ="color" should be created dynamically (it's okay no need to solve it). Any thanks for your help. how to asign contextmenu with this code, see my answer and you will realized what I mean

Comment: glad it helped. :)

Comment: how to assign these functions with contextmenu.See my code in the answer section,  I tried but function are overlapping with eachother.

Comment: how to use localstorage with this color picker, this may become helpful to you http://jsfiddle.net/4U7ky/